# How to download a binary file via Net::HTTP::Get?

Tags: ruby, net-http

I am trying to download a binary file via HTTP using the following Ruby script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

def http_download(resource, filename, debug = false)
  uri = URI.parse(resource)
  puts "Starting HTTP download for: #{uri}"
  http_object = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  http_object.use_ssl = true if uri.scheme == 'https'
  begin
    http_object.start do |http|
      request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri.request_uri
      Net::HTTP.get_print(uri) if debug
      http.read_timeout = 500
      http.request request do |response|
        open filename, 'w' do |io|
          response.read_body do |chunk|
            io.write chunk
          end
        end
      end
    end
  rescue Exception => e
    puts "=> Exception: '#{e}'. Skipping download."
    return
  end
  puts "Stored download as #{filename}."
end
```

However it downloads the HTML source instead of the binary. When I enter the URL in the browser the binary file is downloaded. Here is a URL with which the script fails:

```
http://dcatlas.dcgis.dc.gov/catalog/download.asp?downloadID=2175&downloadTYPE=KML
```

I execute the script as follows

```
pry> require 'myscript'
pry> resource = "http://dcatlas.dcgis.dc.gov/catalog/download.asp?downloadID=2175&downloadTYPE=KML"
pry> http_download(resource,"StreetTreePt.KML", true)
```

How can I download the binary?

## Redirection experiments

I found this [redirection check](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#label-Following+Redirection) which looks quite reasonable. When I integrate in the response block it fails with the following error:

```
Exception: 'undefined method `host' for "save_download.asp?filename=StreetTreePt.KML":String'. Skipping download.
```

The exception does not occur in the "original" function posted above.

Comment: try replacing `w` with `wb` in this line `open filename, 'w' do |io|`

Comment: @orde No change. I do not think it's about storing the data in binary mode. The problem seems to be that the request is redirected.

Comment: You need to show how you've incorporated the redirection. The example code for Net::HTTP works, so the problem is in your code.

Comment: @theTinMan I added the imports and how I execute the script. - I am confused! Did you run my script and it works for you?

Answer (score 3):

The documentation for Net::HTTP shows [how to handle redirects](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#label-Following+Redirection):

> Following Redirection
>
> Each Net::HTTPResponse object belongs to a class for its response code.
>
> For example, all 2XX responses are instances of a Net::HTTPSuccess subclass, a 3XX response is an instance of a Net::HTTPRedirection subclass and a 200 response is an instance of the Net::HTTPOK class. For details of response classes, see the section “HTTP Response Classes” below.
>
> Using a case statement you can handle various types of responses properly:

```
def fetch(uri_str, limit = 10)
  # You should choose a better exception.
  raise ArgumentError, 'too many HTTP redirects' if limit == 0

  response = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI(uri_str))

  case response
  when Net::HTTPSuccess then
    response
  when Net::HTTPRedirection then
    location = response['location']
    warn "redirected to #{location}"
    fetch(location, limit - 1)
  else
    response.value
  end
end

print fetch('http://www.ruby-lang.org')
```

Or, you can use Ruby's [OpenURI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html), which handles it automatically. Or, the [Curb](https://github.com/taf2/curb) gem will do it. Probably [Typhoeus](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus) and [HTTPClient](https://github.com/nahi/httpclient) too.

According to the code you show in your question, the exception you are getting can only come from:

```
http_object = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
```

which is hardly likely since `uri` is a URI object. You need to show the complete code if you want help with that problem.

Comment: Running the function I posted above does **not raise an exception**. Simply the HTML file is downloaded instead of the binary file. The exception mentioned in my post relates to the redirect experiments. I updated my post to clarify this fact.

Comment: @theTinMan I successfully tried OpenURI as you suggested. Nevertheless, I am still interested how to handle the redirect in my example.

Comment: The example given by the Net::HTTP docs for handling redirection works correctly so use that.